# How to add item in Listview on WPF

Tags: wpf, vb.net, listview

I can add column in `ListView`, but it is so difficult to add an item in `ListView`. Here is my code:

```
    Dim myGridView As New GridView
    myGridView.AllowsColumnReorder = True
    myGridView.ColumnHeaderToolTip = "Employee Information"

    Dim gvc1 As New GridViewColumn
    gvc1.DisplayMemberBinding = New Binding("FirstName")
    gvc1.Header = "FirstName"
    gvc1.Width = 100
    myGridView.Columns.Add(gvc1)
    Dim gvc2 As New GridViewColumn
    gvc2.DisplayMemberBinding = New Binding("LastName")
    gvc2.Header = "Last Name"
    gvc2.Width = 100
    myGridView.Columns.Add(gvc2)
    Dim gvc3 As New GridViewColumn()
    gvc3.DisplayMemberBinding = New Binding("EmployeeNumber")
    gvc3.Header = "Employee No."
    gvc3.Width = 100
    listview.View = myGridView
```

I just created `ListViewItem.add` and then used the `subitem` to add more items in a row. But now it's different. How can I add item in `listview` in WPF WITHOUT creating a new class, because the number of the columns of data is dynamic.

**EDIT:**

I had been surfing the internet for hours but found nothing of great help.
Everywhere, it is done using class with predefined numbers of column, while I want to add column item based on database which should have different Ipnumber of columns.

Comment: Creating rows is as easy as writing `myGridView.ItemsSource = myEmployeeCollection`. Just use [Data Binding](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms752347%28v=vs.110%29.aspx#binding_to_collections).

Comment: itemssource property not found :(

Comment: Oh, you're using that old `ListView` mode. I see, your example is straight from [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.gridview%28v=vs.110%29.aspx). Continue reading [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms747048%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) then, it has all the info you need.

Comment: i've already read it..found no guide for add an item to the listview :(

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should initialize the object collection in your code, for example `Employees`.

```
Imports System.ComponentModel
Imports System.Collections.ObjectModel

Public Class EmployeeInformation
  Public Property FirstName As String
  Public Property LastName As String
  Public Property EmployeeNumber As Integer
End Class

Class MainWindow
  Public Property Employees As ObservableCollection(Of EmployeeInformation)

  Public Sub New()
    ' This call is required by the designer.
    InitializeComponent()

    ' Add any initialization after the InitializeComponent() call.
    InitEmploeesCollection(10)
    DataContext = Me
  End Sub

  Private Sub InitEmploeesCollection(count As Integer)
    Employees = New ObservableCollection(Of EmployeeInformation)()

    For index = 1 To count
      Employees.Add(New EmployeeInformation() With {
                    .FirstName = "FirstName" & index,
                    .LastName = "LastName" & index,
                    .EmployeeNumber = index})
    Next
  End Sub
End Class
```

And then you can simply bind it to the `ListView`:

```
<ListView ItemsSource="{Binding Path=Employees}">
    <ListView.View>
        <GridView AllowsColumnReorder="True" ColumnHeaderToolTip="Employee Information">
            <GridViewColumn Header="First Name" Width="100" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Path=FirstName}"/>
            <GridViewColumn Header="Last Name" Width="100" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Path=LastName}"/>
            <GridViewColumn Header="Employee No." Width="100" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Path=EmployeeNumber}"/>
        </GridView>
    </ListView.View>
</ListView>
```

---

To initialize columns dynamically, you can add the code from your question. It doesn't make difference if you are taking data from database. Just fill in `Employees` collection and bind it to the `ListView`.

```
Imports System.ComponentModel
Imports System.Collections.ObjectModel

Class MainWindow

  Public Property Employees As ObservableCollection(Of EmployeeInformation)

  Public Sub New()

    ' This call is required by the designer.
    InitializeComponent()

    ' Add any initialization after the InitializeComponent() call.
    InitEmploeesCollection(10)
    SetGridViewDynamically()
    DataContext = Me

  End Sub

  Private Sub InitEmploeesCollection(count As Integer)
    Employees = New ObservableCollection(Of EmployeeInformation)()

    For index = 1 To count
      Employees.Add(New EmployeeInformation() With {
                    .FirstName = "FirstName" & index,
                    .LastName = "LastName" & index,
                    .EmployeeNumber = index})
    Next
  End Sub

  Private Sub SetGridViewDynamically()
    Dim myGridView As New GridView
    myGridView.AllowsColumnReorder = True
    myGridView.ColumnHeaderToolTip = "Employee Information"

    Dim gvc1 As New GridViewColumn
    gvc1.DisplayMemberBinding = New Binding("FirstName")
    gvc1.Header = "FirstName"
    gvc1.Width = 100
    myGridView.Columns.Add(gvc1)

    Dim gvc2 As New GridViewColumn
    gvc2.DisplayMemberBinding = New Binding("LastName")
    gvc2.Header = "Last Name"
    gvc2.Width = 100
    myGridView.Columns.Add(gvc2)

    Dim gvc3 As New GridViewColumn()
    gvc3.DisplayMemberBinding = New Binding("EmployeeNumber")
    gvc3.Header = "Employee No."
    gvc3.Width = 100
    myGridView.Columns.Add(gvc3)

    ListView1.View = myGridView
  End Sub
End Class

Public Class EmployeeInformation
  Public Property FirstName As String
  Public Property LastName As String
  Public Property EmployeeNumber As Integer
End Class
```

This way XAML will look like this.

```
<ListView Name="ListView1" ItemsSource="{Binding Path=Employees}"/>
```

Comment: thanks but..look on the xaml. the column is predefined..all i want is, add column dynamically based on database table,and add record based on database too..not predefined column.. :(

Comment: application im developing is editing database table with ADODB classic,with the listview as the recordset position navigator..

Answer (score 1):

```
Dim row As String() = New String() {"John", "Doe", "1"}
myGridView.Rows.Add(row)
```

Is this what you're looking for?

Comment: @adjen towfeek btw, im using LISTVIEW.i use your code like this:   `code` Dim row As String() = New String() {"John", "Doe", "1"}
listview.Items.Add(row)`code` not work

Answer (score 0):

XAML part of your program must be like be this:

```
            <ListView x:Name="lvPencere" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="156" Grid.Row="1" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="309">
                <ListView.View>
                    <GridView>
                        <GridView.Columns>
                            <GridViewColumn Header="PencereSN" Width="0" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding PencereSN}"/>
                            <GridViewColumn Header="Pencere Adı" Width="300" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding PencereAD}"/>
                        </GridView.Columns>
                    </GridView>
                </ListView.View>
            </ListView>
```

And your VB part must be like this:

```
Listview.Items.Add(New With {Key .PencereSN = "some string", Key .PencereAD = "some string"})
```